# Goto last line in org-table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In org-mode, I need a function to move point to the last row of a named table of arbitrary length.

**Example:**

From anywhere in the buffer, I would like to go to:

```
#+NAME: table-with-unique-name
|---+---------|
| X | Y       |
|---+---------|
| a | some    |
| b | random  |
| c | content | <--first cell in this row
|---+---------|
```

So:

- I there a more elegant way to go to a named table than to isearch for
  `#+NAME: table-with-unique-name` and `next-line`?

**EDIT:** ok, so I'm going with a function that searches for the `#+NAME: table-with-unique-name` line and goes to `next-line` but that, too, is giving me trouble. With this function:

```
(defun test-goto-table ()
  (interactive)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "^#\\+NAME: table-with-unique-name")
    (next-line))
```

I can successfully go to the table if it exists but if the search fails, point ends up in the beginning of the buffer. Is there a way to wrap `re-search-forward` or some other smart way to search the whole buffer? [Resolved by using `save-excursion`. See "Edit 2" for working function.]

- [Answered] Once at the table, how can I go to the last line? (I know
  there's a    function    called `org-table-goto-line` but I can't get
  it to go to    last line, only to    a specific line number.)

**EDIT 2:** This works to goto specific cell of a table with a unique name:

```
(defun tracktable-exists-p ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "^#\\+NAME: table-with-unique-name" nil t)))

(defun test-goto-cell ()
  (interactive)
  (if (tracktable-exists-p)
      (let ((tabel "^#\\+NAME: table-with-unique-name"))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (re-search-forward tabel nil t)
        (show-subtree) ; necessary if the table is hidden in a subtree
        (goto-char (org-table-end))
        (previous-line 2) ; the dotted line in the bottom is not recognized as part of the table by 'org-table-goto-column' so go two lines up.
        (org-table-goto-column 1))
    (message "table-with-unique-name doesn't exist")))
```

Marco Wahl resolved the hard part, so accepting answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an answer to 'Once at the table, how can I go to the last line?'.  So this is only a partial answer.

You can use this command which at its core uses the function 'org-table-end'.

```
(defun stackexchange-org-table-goto-last-line ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (org-table-end))
  (backward-char)
  (org-table-goto-column 1))
```

Comment: Thx. I reformulated the other part of my question. If perchance you can answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled to move my cursor in long org tables to last row, and was using [Marco Wahl Accepted Answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17858/38917), but recently I accidentally found `org-forward-paragraph` (keybinding: `C-down`), which also moves point to last line of table.